# regular exp in oracle

Tags: regex, oracle

I have a table that has the column values like this.

```
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time} .The CIRCUIT is missing.    
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time}. The JOB_STREET_NAME is missing.    
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time}. The JOB_TOWN is missing.
```

I wanted to find for {Date/Time} part in that particular column in my oracle package and replace it with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

Not able to find anything that works for me. I am new to this. Looking for suggestions.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  Please use an [ascii table generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/) and edit the question to show the data in a readable format with sample data that is *exact* Not "{Date/Time}", and also what you have tried, and the expected output

Comment: Instead of monkeying about with regex, a simple [`REPLACE()`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions134.htm) should suffice. That is unless you don't literally mean `{Date/Time}` string needs replacing. That's not clear though.

Comment: edited the question. I just wanted to know the regular expression which can be used here to achieve the objective. I tried only REPLACE but that wont work for me

Comment: You will definitely need to share some sample of what those date/time strings actually look to build a regex that can match them as formats of date and time vary wildly.

Comment: {Date/Time} needs to be replaced with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP everytime that message is fetched.

Comment: the timestamp can look like '25-MAR-20 08.19.20.617189000 AM'

Comment: So you need to explain why it "won't work for me".  I think you should also explain the larger context. Is the '{Date/Time}' literally the value, or are you just showing it as a place holder?  If it is literally the value, why would you want to replace it in the table with sysdate?  Looks to me like this table is template error messages and instead of replacing '{Date/Time}' with sysdate _in the table_ you'd replace it as presented to the client.  You need to clarify a lot.

Comment: @EdStevens You are right. This table just holds the value. When i fetch it in my package at a particular time, i need it to update that {date/time} part with the timestamp. This will be then inserted in another table.

Comment: This question is **very** close to be closed. Please, post an example of what you really have and what you want to get as a result. I don't know whether your rows actually contain string `{Date/Time}` which should be replaced with another string - `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, or is there some value (e.g. 13.01.2020 13:57) which has to be replaced with 25.03.2020 18:07 (which is right now).

Comment: Some advice: You said "I tried only REPLACE but that wont work for me", but that doesn't mean that REPLACE isn't the right tool to use.  When you're stuck on a problem like that, rather than deciding "I couldn't get REPLACE to work, so I'll try regular expressions", post a question showing the code that you tried, and what you wanted to do,  Then we can solve your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve it using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` as follows:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR(YOUR_COL,'failed to load service request on(.+) \.',1,1,NULL,1) 
FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Comment: this expression only works for :

"ERROR - abc failed to load service request on <Date/Time> .The CIRCUIT is missing."

Comment: it returns null for others:

WARNING - The JOB_BLDG_LOT_NO was not provided by abc on <Date/Time>.

ERROR - abc failed to load service request on <Date/Time>. The JOB_STREET_NAME is missing.

ERROR - abc failed to load service request on <Date/Time>. The JOB_TOWN is missing.

 ERROR - abc failed to load service request on <Date/Time>. The JOB_STATE is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A simple REPLACE function seems to work just fine.

```
SQL> -- create an populate table
SQL> create table errmsg (msg_id number,
  2                       msg_txt varchar2(100)
  3                      )
  4  ;

Table created.

SQL> insert into errmsg values (1,'ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time} .The CIRCUIT is missing.');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into errmsg values (2,'ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time}. The JOB_STREET_NAME is missing.');

1 row created.

SQL> insert into errmsg values (3,'ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time}. The JOB_TOWN is missing.');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from errmsg;

    MSG_ID
----------
MSG_TXT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time} .The CIRCUIT is missin
g.


ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time} .The CIRCUIT is missin
g.

         2
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time}. The JOB_STREET_NAME i
s missing.

         3
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on {Date/Time}. The JOB_TOWN is missi
ng.


3 rows selected.

SQL> -- test the method
SQL> select replace(msg_txt,'{Date/Time}',to_char(sysdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) logged_message
  2  from errmsg
  3  where msg_id=1;

LOGGED_MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on 25-Mar-2020 16:16:39 .The CIRCUIT
is missing.


1 row selected.

SQL> --
SQL> select replace(msg_txt,'{Date/Time}',to_char(sysdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) logged_message
  2  from errmsg
  3  where msg_id=2;

LOGGED_MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on 25-Mar-2020 16:16:39. The JOB_STRE
ET_NAME is missing.


1 row selected.

SQL> --
SQL> select replace(msg_txt,'{Date/Time}',to_char(sysdate,'dd-Mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) logged_message
  2  from errmsg
  3  where msg_id=3;

LOGGED_MESSAGE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR - abc failed to load service request on 25-Mar-2020 16:16:39. The JOB_TOWN
 is missing.


1 row selected.

SQL> --
SQL> -- drop the table
SQL> drop table errmsg purge;

Table dropped.

SQL> spool off
```